# Study materials to help understand the generalized Stokes' theorem both intuitively and rigorously?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, self-learning, book-recommendation, differential-forms

Dear MSE: My goal is to understand [the generalized Stokes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem) both intuitively and rigorously. Could someone give advice or recommend study materials to help understand the generalized Stokes' theorem both intuitively and rigorously?

Baby Rudin seems to contain a terse treatment of the generalized Stokes' theorem in Chapter 10: Integration of Differential Forms. Are there study materials suitable to accompany Baby Rudin's terse treatment?

Comment: I suggest the book "Vector Analysis" by Jänich.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The treatment in Baby Rudin is awful. I don't think I've met anyone who wasn't thoroughly confused by it. You are not alone. (And I would caution against trying to read the later chapters, too. In particular, please don't try to learn Lebesgue integration from that book.)

A proper treatment requires learning some basic differential geometry. My favorite introduction is Loring Tu's *Introduction to Manifolds*. It covers all the material necessary for Stokes's theorem, proves the theorem, and does even more.

As far as intuition goes, you should think of Stokes's theorem as a generalized version of theorems like the fundamental theorem of calculus and Green's theorem. Stokes's theorem says
$$\int_{\partial M} \omega = \int_M d\omega,$$
where $M$ is some manifold and $\omega$ is some "differential form" on $M$, and $\partial M$ is the boundary of $M$.

When $M$ is an interval $[a,b]$, we get
$$\int_{\{a,b\}} f = \int_{[a,b]} f'(x)\, dx$$
which is just the usual fundamental theorem of calculus. Here the boundary of $M=[a,b]$ is just the set of endpoints $\{a,b\}$, and $\omega=f$.

We can also look the case when $M$ is some two-dimensional domain in the plane. It turns out that in this case Stokes's theorem recovers Green's theorem.